# Reversing evaluation of Boole

Tags: boolean-computation

I am currently using

```
TransferFunctionPoles[TransferFunctionModel[{{A[w]}}, w]][[1, 1]]
```

to identify the poles of some function $A(w)$. However, $A$ contains one or more `Boole` operators and `TransferFunctionModel` can only deal with them if they have not yet been evaluated. When the `Boole` operators have already been expanded, the line above returns an error.

Simple example of typical form of $A(w)$:

$A(\omega \ ; q,k,\epsilon,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda}{i \omega + q^2(1 + \epsilon) + (k^2 - q^2) \text{Boole} [ k^2/q^2 - 1>0]}$

I seem to have no control over whether the `Boole`'s in $A$ are evaluated or not (in some cases they are, in others they aren't). Is there any way of forcing all those `Boole` operators that have already been evaluated back into a non-evaluated form, so that I can make sure that the $A$ I feed into `TransferFunctionModel` has the right form?

Comment: Can you give an example $A$, hopefully one that is simple?

Comment: Example added to the question.

Comment: `Boole` takes a Boolean argument, while yours seems to be numeric.

Comment: My fault, argument fixed.